# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ZFS filesystem disk space disappeared

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, zfs

As seen in the following screenshot, some disk space from my 507 GB hard disk has disappeared.

53 GB (`/`) + 232 GB (`/home`) = 285 GB

[image: various disc utilities]

Where did the remaining 222 GB go?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information provided with the picture we need to know about the pool created.

```
root@zeus-H370M:~# zpool import -af
root@zeus-H370M:~# zpool status
  pool: WD4
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    WD4                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-00SPEB0_WD-WCC4E6TYUHK2  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
root@zeus-H370M:~# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
WD4   3.62T  1.20T  2.42T        -         -     0%    33%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

The output of fdisk -l /dev/sd? would be nice, to see if you have another partition on the drive too.